# Why need with statements for reader and writer be nested?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io, with-statement, pypdf

```
with open(pdf,'rb') as fin:
    reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(fin)
    new_pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()

    for i in range(reader.numPages):
        new_pdf.addPage(reader.getPage(i))

    out_file = pdf if not create_copy else self._new_copy(pdf)
    with open(out_file,'wb') as fout:
        new_pdf.write(fout)
```

This works as intended when writing a copy.

Now let's move the last three lines out of the `with`:

```
with open(pdf,'rb') as fin:
    reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(fin)
    new_pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()

    for i in range(reader.numPages):
        new_pdf.addPage(reader.getPage(i))

out_file = pdf if not create_copy else self._new_copy(pdf)
with open(out_file,'wb') as fout:
    new_pdf.write(fout)
```

This creates a pdf with the correct amount of pages, **but** all the pages are blank, *even* when writing to a new file. (note that moving the `new_pdf = ...` out, too, doesn't change anything)

Why? And what can I do about it? Because I expect to have to move these three lines out of the first `with`, eventually, in order to provide overwriting support. (Unless I just create a copy anyway and then rename, which I kind of want to avoid.)

Comment: Does it really work in the first case to have the same file opened both for reading and for writing `if not create_copy`?

Comment: @AndreasDeak of course not.

Comment: I can only guess here, but maybe `addPage` does not really copy the page into `new_pdf` but only a reference to the original file, and then that file is closed at the end of `with`.

Comment: @tobias_k I modified the method to open the file in ``r+b`` when ``create_copy`` is set to ``False``. That way I can simply pass ``fin`` as an argument to ``new_pdf.write()``. That works, so I suspect you're correct. Want to make an answer out of your comment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is kind of a wild guess, as I am not familiar with the module and did not bother to [read the source code](https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2).

However, from the documentation, it seems that [`PdfFileWriter.addPage`](https://pythonhosted.org/PyPDF2/PdfFileWriter.html#PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter.addPage) expects a [`PageObject`](https://pythonhosted.org/PyPDF2/PageObject.html#PyPDF2.pdf.PageObject), which has a reference to the PDF file the page belongs to. So my guess is that `addPage` does not immediately create a copy of, but just a reference to the page in the original PDF, and when that file is closed before the new PDF has been written, the content of that page is lost.